# Python - how do I utilise a module in a git submodule I have added?

Tags: python, git

I have a Python module, call it `module.py`, that another Python script (`main.py`) uses. Currently, I am just including both in the same directory e.g. **proj/test** and then importing `module.py` using:

`import module`

However, `module.py` is already included in another repo (`submodule-repo-test`). I am able to add this repo to my main project by running:

`git submodule add ../../../url/of/submodule-repo-test` - in `.gitmodules`, you can then see the following:

```
[submodule "submodule-repo-test"]
    path = submodule-repo-test
    url = ../../../url/of/submodule-repo-test
```

In this now added submodule, `module.py` is now located at: `proj/submodule-repo-test/src/lib`

How can I import the module from here? I have tried the following:

- Getting the current directory of main.py, adding the submodule's path to sys.path and then importing the module:

```
current_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

submodule_path = os.path.join(current_dir, '..', 'submodule-repo-test')
sys.path.append(submodule_path)

from src.lib import module
```

- Appending the path to the submodule using sys: `sys.path.append('path/to/submodule')` and then trying to import from there
- Trying to do `from submodule-repo-test.src.lib import module` - this seems to give me a syntax error due to the dashes in the submodule name for some reason

Does anyone know of a way to do what I am trying to achieve?

Comment: In your first attempt, change the last line to `import module`. Will this work?

Comment: @liginity do you mean just import instead of including the from src.lib?

Comment: yes, have you tried it?

Comment: @liginity no that didn't seem to work

Comment: how about changing 2 lines: `submodule_path = os.path.join(current_dir, '..', 'submodule-repo-test', 'src', 'lib')` and `import module`?